# Breakpoint doesn't go through delegate C# Visual Studio (UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

I have a problem debugging on my code. Here's a screenshot of it on Visual Studio 2017

[image]

On my `Debug.LogError();` I could still proceed but then if i try to go through the delegate it stops debugging . I want to see what's happening on my code inside the delegate . Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Did you try to use a separate function instead of delegate? Maybe something to do with Unity using some old c# standard.

Comment: Have you tried putting the breakpoint on a line of code, not the block marker (`{`)? What do you mean by "stops debugging"? Do you mean it just goes back to execution? I suspect you are skipping over the delegate code because there is no breakpoint in it.

Comment: The LogError is before theStartCheckNetwork. It is part of the main thread so to say. The delegate is a callback to StartCheckNetwork so it will be called later. when ready The first breakpoint is likely to stall all threads, have you tried removing the first breakpoint or placing a debug inside the callback?

Comment: @ColinYoung Yes I did . "Stops debugging" means it skips then starts my unity project into playmode.

Comment: @Everts I've tried placing the debug inside the callback but it doesn't execute/debug there. it just skips.

Comment: @BoonMingProg To confirm, you've placed a breakpoint on line 204, not 202 as shown in your screenshot?

Comment: Have you simply tried to print something from inside? I am not familiar enough with breakpoint but I know printing has to work.